# SoapUI -Groovy XML.Markupbuilder if condition

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have the following code which is working well and building a request based on the response of a previous request. What I need to do now is put a condition in to only build the node if question.HasAnomaly is true.
    true. 
How can I include an if condition in the code below to only include nodes with the tag set as true?

```
root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def sw = new StringWriter()
def request = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)

request.UpdateTargetGroupList{
       root.Body.GetQualityIndicatorsResponse.GetQualityIndicatorsOutput.QIDetails.GroupList.Group.each{group->
//Group{
    ID(group.ID)
    RowVersion(group.RowVersion)
    QuestionList{
    group.QuestionList.Question.each{question->
    Question(){
        ID(question.ID)
        RowVersion(question.RowVersion)
        QuestionType(question.QuestionType)
        TargetValue(question.TargetValue)

    }
    }
}
}
}
}

log.info sw
```

Comment: Have you got chance to look at the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Used your sample code to show how to add the node conditionally. See the below example.

Introduced a boolean variable `isTargetValue` and assigned `true`. Of course, you may use it for any element based on your need.

```
def isTargetValue = true
root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def sw = new StringWriter()
def request = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw)

request.UpdateTargetGroupList {
   root.Body.GetQualityIndicatorsResponse.GetQualityIndicatorsOutput.QIDetails.GroupList.Group.each { group->
        ID(group.ID)
        RowVersion(group.RowVersion)
        QuestionList {
            group.QuestionList.Question.each { question->
                Question(){
                    ID(question.ID)
                    RowVersion(question.RowVersion)
                    QuestionType(question.QuestionType)
                    if (isTargetValue) {
                        TargetValue(question.TargetValue)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

log.info sw
```

Hope this helps.